# Figuring Out the Play Framework 2 Asset Pipeline

Tags: javascript, playframework-2.0, webjars

I made a [GitHub project](https://github.com/mslinn/playAssets) for this question.

1. CSS and image fingerprinting is working
2. Fetching JQuery via webjars is working
3. I want to combine and minify all `.js` files into `main.js` for prod mode, with the exception of JS fetched via WebJars. Currently all JS, including WebJars jS is combined and minified, but not loaded; this takes a really long time and they end up in `target/web/uglify/build/main.min.js`, which is not loaded.
4. In dev mode it would be fine to load all .js files separately or together (I don't care), but I don't want them to be minified.

I do not want to use NodeJS or any NodeJS utilities; I expect that SBT should be sufficient.

EDIT:
I tried adding this to build.sbt, but it seemed to have no effect:

```
UglifyKeys.uglifyOps := { js =>
  Seq((js.filterNot(_._1.getName.endsWith(".min.js")).sortBy(_._2), "main.min.js"))
}
```